# Lazarus error External: SIGSEGV

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Не понимаю, в чем ошибка. Уже все перепробовал. 
Код:

```
 unit Unit3;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

 interface

uses
   Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,      ExtCtrls,
   Buttons, StdCtrls;

type
    uk=^O;
    O=object
    data:integer;
    next:uk;
end;

type

  { TForm3 }

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn2: TBitBtn;
    Button1: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    Image10: TImage;
    Image11: TImage;
    Image2: TImage;
    Image3: TImage;
    Image4: TImage;
    Image5: TImage;
    Image6: TImage;
    Image7: TImage;
    Image8: TImage;
    Image9: TImage;
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure closedln(k:integer);
    procedure CreateLol(var first: uk; s: string);
    procedure printi(k,n:integer);
    procedure Push(var stack: uk; inf: integer);
    function Empty(stack: uk): boolean;
    function Pop(var stack: uk): integer;
    procedure SortStack(var first: uk; var second: uk; var third: uk);
    procedure PrintStack(second: uk);
    procedure Viv(second1: uk);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
    Form3: TForm3;
    first, second, third : uk;

implementation
      uses Unit4;

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm3 }
procedure TForm3.closedln(k:integer);    //удаление картинки с формы
begin
   case k of
    1:Image2.Visible:=false;
    2:Image3.Visible:=false;
    3:Image4.Visible:=false;
    4:Image5.Visible:=false;
    5:Image6.Visible:=false;
    6:Image7.Visible:=false;
    7:Image8.Visible:=false;
    8:Image9.Visible:=false;
    9:Image10.Visible:=false;
    10:Image11.Visible:=false;
end;
end;

procedure TForm3.printi(k, n : integer);  //вывод картинки в положенном  месте
var
  s1:string;
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages();
  s1 := inttostr(n);
  s1 := s1 +'.png';
  case k of
   1:begin
      Image2.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image2.Visible:=true;
   end;
   2:begin
      Image3.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image3.Visible:=true;
   end;
   3:begin
     Image4.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image4.Visible:=true;
   end;
   4:begin
      Image5.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image5.Visible:=true;
   end;
   5:begin
      Image6.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image6.Visible:=true;
   end;
   6:begin
      Image7.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image7.Visible:=true;
   end;
   7:begin
      Image8.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image8.Visible:=true;
   end;
   8:begin
      Image9.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image9.Visible:=true;
   end;
   9:begin
      Image10.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image10.Visible:=true;
   end;
   10:begin
      Image11.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
      Image11.Visible:=true;
   end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.CreateLol(var first: uk; s: string);//создание стека
var
  k, kol: integer;
begin
   k:=0;
   kol:=0;
   repeat
     k := k + 1;
     if (s[k]='1') and (k+1<=length(s)) and (s[k+1]='0') then
        begin
           Push(first,10);
           k+=1;
           kol+=1;
        end
     else
        if (s[k] in ['0'..'9']) then
           begin
                Push(first,StrToInt(s[k]));
                kol+=1;
           end;
  until k>=length(s);
end;



procedure TForm3.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);//закрытие формы
begin
  form3.close;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  s: string;
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages();

  new(first);//создаем три указателя и обнуляем их
  new(second);
  new(third);
  first:= nil;
  second:= nil;
  third:= nil;

  s := Unit4.s;
  Application.ProcessMessages();

  CreateLol(first, s);
  Application.ProcessMessages();


  viv(first);
  SortStack(first, second, third);
  Application.ProcessMessages();

  PrintStack(second);
end;


procedure TForm3.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm3.Viv(second1: uk);//вывод стека в ShowBox
var
  newUk, newUk2: uk;
  s: string;
begin
   new(newUk);
   new(newUk2);
   s:= '';
   newUk:= second1;
   while ( Empty(newUk) = false ) do begin
         s:= s + inttostr(newUk^.data);
         s:= s + ' ';
         newUk2:= newUk^.next;
         newUk:= newUk2;
   end;
   s:= 'Вывожу стек: ' + s;
   ShowMessage(s);
end;

procedure TForm3.SortStack(var first: uk; var second: uk; var third: uk);//сортировка стека first, результат - в стек second
var
  el: integer;
begin
     Application.ProcessMessages();
     ShowMessage ('Начинаю сортировать');

     while ( Empty(first) = false ) do begin  //ПОКА не пуст ПервСтек ВЫПОЛНЯТЬ:

     //ЕСЛИ РезСтек пуст ИЛИ Вершина.РезСтек < Вершина.ПервСтек ТОГДА
         if ( ( Empty(second) = true ) or ( second^.data < first^.data ) ) then
            Push(second, Pop(first))//ДОСТАТЬ вершину из ПервСтек и ДОБАВИТЬ в РезСтек,
         else //ИНАЧЕ


         begin
              if (third = nil) then ShowMessage ('third = nil ');
          //ПОКА не пуст РезСтек ИЛИ Вершина.РезСтек > Вершина.ПервСтек ВЫПОЛНЯТЬ:
              while ( ( Empty(second) = false ) or ( second^.data > first^.data ) ) do
                    Push( third, Pop(second) );//ДОСТАТЬ вершину из РезСтек и ДОБАВИТЬ во ВремСтек.

              Push(second, pop(first));//ДОСТАТЬ вершину из ПервСтек и ДОБАВИТЬ в РезСтек.

              while ( Empty(third) = false ) do//ПОКА не пуст ВремСтек:
                    Push(second, Pop(third)); //ДОСТАТЬ вершину из ВремСтек и ДОБАВИТЬ в РезСтек.
         end;
         Application.ProcessMessages();
     end;
end;

procedure TForm3.Push(var stack: uk; inf: integer);  //добавление элемента в стек, на вход указатель стека и data
var
   newUk : uk;
begin
     new(newUk);
     Application.ProcessMessages();
     if ( stack = nil ) then
        begin
             newUk^.data:= inf;
             newUK^.next:= stack;
        end
     else
     begin
           newUk^.data:= inf;
           newUK^.next:= stack;
     end;
     stack:= newUK;
end;

function TForm3.Empty(stack: uk): boolean;//проверка на пустоту. True - пустой, False - нет
begin
     Application.ProcessMessages();
     if ( stack = nil ) then
        Empty:= true
     else
         Empty:= false;
end;

function TForm3.Pop(var stack: uk): integer; //удаление элемента из стека
var
   newUk : uk;
begin
     if (stack <> nil) then
     begin
          Application.ProcessMessages();
          Pop:= stack^.data;
          new(newUk);
          newUk:= stack;
          stack:= stack^.next;
          dispose(newUk);
    end
 else
     ShowMessage ('В попе почему-то у нас нил');//на случай ошибок
end;

procedure TForm3.PrintStack(second: uk);   //выводит результат сортировки на форму
var
  i: integer;
begin
     Application.ProcessMessages();
     i:= 0;
     while ( Empty(second) = false) do begin
           Application.ProcessMessages();
           i:= i + 1;
           printi(i,pop(second));  //сам вывод картинки
     end;
end;


procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
   i: integer;
begin
   for i := 1 to 10 do//закрывает все картинки на форме
      closedln(i);
end;

end.
```

Ошибка в:

```
Push( third, Pop(second) );//ДОСТАТЬ вершину из РезСтек и ДОБАВИТЬ во ВремСтек.
```

Три скрина: ошибка, алгоритм, форма (при выводе отсортированного стека)
[image: алгоритм]
[image: ошибка]
[image: форма]

Алгоритм работает на отсортированном стеке, но падает на неотсортированном при попытке добавления (Push) элемента 3 стек (third)

Почему падает, не ясно. 
До этого прекрасно процедура Push работает со стеком номер 1 (first) и стеком номер 2 (second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ломается по причине:
 ПОКА не пуст РезСтек ИЛИ Вершина.РезСтек > Вершина.ПервСтек ВЫПОЛНЯТЬ:

Тут должно быть не логическое ИЛИ, а логическое И

Код:

```
while ( ( Empty(second) = false ) and ( second^.data > first^.data ) ) do
```

Answer (score 1):

Что делает ваша процедура Push?

```
procedure TForm3.Push(var stack: uk; inf: integer);  //добавление элемента в стек, на вход указатель стека и data
var
   newUk : uk;
begin
     new(newUk);
     Application.ProcessMessages(); // зачем это?
     if ( stack = nil ) then // к чему это условие, если делается одно и тоже???
     begin
       newUk^.data:= inf;
       newUK^.next:= stack;
     end
     else
     begin
       newUk^.data:= inf;
       newUK^.next:= stack;
     end;
     stack:= newUK;
end;
```

И еще много лишнего кода по тексту.

Чтобы понять в чем ошибка, напишите **минимальный пример**, воспроизводящий ошибку. Сложно разобраться в этой простыне.

Comment: Push хоть и криво написана, но справляется со своей задачей. До этого Push нормально добавляет элементы в два стека, но на третьем рушится

Comment: Попытайтесь изобразить минимальный пример с тремя стеками, в котором на третьем стеке все рушится. Возможно, вы сами поймёте, что делаете не так.

Comment: Вы правы. Вынес все в отдельный файл, запустил и разобрался в чем проблема. Спасибо!

Comment: Рад, что смог вам помочь :)